# git subtree, view commit

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-subtree

When I merge project into another with `git subtree add` add command, the history is merged with target branch similarly to normal three-way merge.

```
*   375c6d0 Add 'somestuff/' from commit '428761aea39560d87f4dd096366f7324bde728f5'
|\
| * 428761a Add new line to Readme
| * 15b1175 Edit Readme
| * c418c7d Initial commit
* 3782cdd fixes
* bed10f8 parent
* c3dd312 resources filtering
* db3cbd2 property
* 7cc3bc3 submodules
* 3bb1296 Initial commit
```

In this example the branch is the history is from another project merged with `git sutbree add`. What the command does is place the project in new subfolder under main project. However, when I view commits, file paths are shown relatively to the merged project, not relatively to the main project (in which under the merged project now resides, thus all paths should get prefixed with that folder name).

```
$ ls -la
total 29
drwxr-xr-x 1 tuoppi 197121    0 Sep  4 06:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 tuoppi 197121    0 Sep  4 06:22 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 tuoppi 197121    0 Sep  4 06:29 .git/
-rw-r--r-- 1 tuoppi 197121  391 Sep  2 16:14 .project
drwxr-xr-x 1 tuoppi 197121    0 Sep  2 16:14 .settings/
drwxr-xr-x 1 tuoppi 197121    0 Sep  4 06:26 bar/
drwxr-xr-x 1 tuoppi 197121    0 Sep  4 06:26 common/
drwxr-xr-x 1 tuoppi 197121    0 Sep  4 06:26 foo/
-rw-r--r-- 1 tuoppi 197121 1243 Sep  4 06:26 pom.xml
drwxr-xr-x 1 tuoppi 197121    0 Sep  4 06:28 somestuff/

git show c418c7d

commit c418c7d17ae70248e5e56a821b84ffaee6e8bdf5
Author: Your Name <you@example.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 4 06:23:21 2017 +0200

Initial commit

diff --git a/README.mf b/README.mf
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
```

Why git doesn't refactor those commits in respect to new file paths? Is there some argument to do so?

Comment: I can see a reason : commit `c418c7d` has no idea whatsoever of the existence of `somestuff/`. What does `git show 375c6d0` say ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be trivial for git to rebase these commit according to new path?

Comment: `git subtree add` directly imports the other repo's history. Changing the path would meean changing the tree and the commit ids. It *can* be done, it just isn't what this command does AFAIK.